# Vue.js components - handling translations within a component library from a consuming project without repetition

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I fully expect this is a little niche, and I'm not sure if there's a solution, but I have an interesting situation.

We have a library of Vue components we use in our projects, from form fields to data tables. Some of these components need aria labels, buttons, labels, messages, and so on. Most of our projects will need translating into any number of languages, on the fly, often via user-selectable drop-down menus. Translation is handled by Vue i18n.

I have begun adding slots and props as required to allow this translation, but I realise it's going to be a lot of repetition to use the components, as it will be necessary to translate them each time they are used, some of which may be used hundreds of times in a large project.

The components are part of a library which has no knowledge of any current translation, and won't have access to the translated strings.

What I'm wondering is if anyone has an idea for how to essentially say **'here are some default slots and props for this component, which will override the defaults set in the component itself, but will apply every time I use this component in this project unless otherwise stated'**.

I can't make these the defaults in the component itself, as what the default will be differs from user to user.

The only two thoughts I've had are:

1. Somehow passing the instance of the vue-i18n plugin to the components as they're used, allowing them to find their own translation strings.
2. Creating 'wrapper' components which are part of the current project, and thus do have access to translations, which can set a lot of these repetitive props and slots for us. This seems pretty reasonable, but doesn't solve where some components use others (e.g. our form components can be used by themselves, or initialised by a form builder, which then wouldn't know to use the 'middleware' components)

Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: I feel like there is a solution to this. I am not sure that I understood you use case entirely. I understand it that you have an external component with default props and slots and you would like to sensibly reuse it in your project.

First thing that comes to my mind is to create a wrapper as you suggest and provide wrap each slot with your own slot. This can have some default definition or left empty as you will. The same would apply for props, define sensible defaults and pass all that to 3rd part component. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a notification about your comment! Yes basically, the same as my option 2 - that's what I ended up doing in the end. It's a bit weird, but for the developer using it it's actually a nice solution as it takes away some complexity, and they don't need to see the wrapper as such.

Comment: This is an absolutely valid approach :) It's especially useful for libraries that are built for vanilla javascript and you'd like to facilitate the API for Vue-based projects. Glad you've figured something out.